# Angular Material mat-select Position

Tags: angular, angular-material, overlay, mat-select

I am using a mat-select in my Angular app and when I select something from the select a mat-chip is created and is being placed above the mat-select. When I select something for the first time the dropdown doesn't change its position and it looks bad.

Here is the base view:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFBYZ.png)

My actual outcome:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1kM4.png)

That is my desired outcome:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T0i3.png)

```
<mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
    <mat-label>{{ 'add.thesis.location' | translate }}</mat-label>
    <mat-select disableOptionCentering multiple class="dropdown-data"
                [(ngModel)]="sharedDataService.selectedLocations" (ngModelChange)="checkSelectedFilters()"
                cdkScrollable>
        <mat-select-trigger matSuffix>
            {{ 'add.thesis.location' | translate }} ({{ sharedDataService.selectedLocations.length }})
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option>
            <ngx-mat-select-search class="button-remove" [formControl]="locationFilterCtrl"
                                   placeholderLabel="{{ 'theses.location.search.input' | translate }}"
                                   noEntriesFoundLabel="{{ 'theses.search.no.entries.found.label' | translate }}"></ngx-mat-select-search>
        </mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let location of filterLocationsTranslated" [value]="location[0]"
                    ngDefaultControl>
            {{ location[1] }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I tried something like this, but it didn't work

```css
.cdk-overlay-pane {
    position: sticky !important;
}
```

Comment: In the [examples from the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples) your case is not reproducible. Your form field looks highly customized (or is it just density?). This can definitely be a problem.